# get total submissions and number of accepted and rejected submissions of all users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in database, from where I have to fetch a list.
First table is users table which is just an ordinary table with information of users. Another table is submissions table which have list of submissions of a user. for instance you can assume this table as follows

```
id user_id submission_name status
1   1         nnnn          pending
2   1         fgs           accepted
3   2         sds           rejected
4   2        asdasd         pending
```

I want to get data as follows
(assuming a left join of users and submissions table)

```
id username   total_submissions accepted_subs rejected_subs pending_subs
1   ABC           2                    1            0         1
2   XYZ           2                    0            1         1
```

I am using mysql. What query can be used get data like this?
I am able to get just this data

```
id username   total_submissions 
    1   ABC           2       
    2   XYZ           2
```

Comment: I don't think there is one - you'll have to write one yourself.  Be sure to ask for help here if what you try doesn't work first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, given the data you have provided, you cannot get the `username`.  But the rest of your question is solved using conditional aggregation:

```
select s.user_id, count(*) as total_submissions,
       sum( s.status = 'accepted' ) as accepted,
       . . .  -- add additional expressions here for other statuses
from submissions s
group by s.user_id;
```

You should be able how to join the tables together to get the user name.